# Volume of Brillouin zone is the same as Fourier primitive cell?

Tags: solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, crystals, volume

In Kittel's solid state text, problem 2.3, he says that the volume of the [Brillouin zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brillouin_zone) is the same as a primitive parallelepiped in Fourier space. Somehow I can't see why this is true. Can someone help me see why this is true? Also, is the same relationship true between Wigner-Seitz cells and primitive parallelepiped in real space?

Answer (score 2):

This has to be true by construction, either in the real space or in the reciprocal space. There is one primitive parallelepiped and one Wigner-Seitz cell per lattice point, and both of them tile the whole space.

Answer (score 0):

It is by definition, and it is defined that way because of convenience. For a single (but not very complete, explanation you check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brillouin_zone